# Extract unique elements from each row of a matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I would like to apply the function unique to each row of a given matrix, without involving any for loop. Suppose I have the following 4-by-5 matrix

```
full(A) = [0    1     0     0    1
           2    1     0     3    0
           1    2     0     0    2
           0    3     1     0    0]
```

where `A` is the corresponding sparse matrix. As an example using a for loop, I can do

```
uniq = cell(4,1);
for i = 1:4
    uniq{i} = unique(A(i,:));
end
```

and I would obtain the cell structure uniq given by

```
uniq{1} = {1}
uniq{2} = {[1 2 3]}
uniq{3} = {[1 2]}
uniq{4} = {[1 3]}
```

Is there a quicker way to vectorize this and avoid for loops? 
I need to apply this to matrices M-by-5 with M large.
Note that I'm not interested in the number of unique elements per row (I know there are around answers for such a problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function:

```
A = sparse([0 1 0 0 1; 2 1 0 3 0; 1 2 0 0 2; 0 3 1 0 0]); % data
[ii, ~, vv] = find(A);
uniq = accumarray(ii(:), vv(:), [], @(x){unique(x.')});
```

This gives:

```
>> celldisp(uniq)
uniq{1} =
     1
uniq{2} =
     1     2     3
uniq{3} =
     1     2
uniq{4} =
     1     3
```

Comment: What can I say... you just saved me again!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `num2cell(A,2)` to convert each row into cell and then `cellfun` with `unique` to get cell array of unique values from each row:

```
% generate large nX5 matrix
n = 5000;
A = randi(5,n,5);    
% convert each row into cell
C = num2cell(A,2);
% take unique values from each cell
U = cellfun(@unique,C,'UniformOutput',0);
```